# Outputting R syntax from within a function

Tags: r, string, function, output

I am teaching a statistics course where I'm trying to gently introduce my students to R syntax (specifically, ggplot). To do so, I have created wrapper functions for many basic commmands. For example:

```
basic.plot.function = function(x,y, data=d){
    p = ggplot(data, aes_string(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth()
    print(p)
    #dput(p) # this function isn't doing what I want it to
}
```

I want the function to output the plot (which is what print(p) does), but I also want it to write to the console the actual code used to create this. In other words, if the user types:

```
mydata = data.frame(x1 = runif(100), x2 = runif(100))
basic.plot.function("x1","x2", data=mydata)
```

I want it to output:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes_string(x="x1", y="x2")) + geom_point() + geom_smooth()
```

Any ideas how I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution

```
library(ggplot2)
basic.plot.function = function(x, y, data = d){
    call <- paste0('ggplot(', deparse(substitute(data)), ', aes_string(x=',
                   deparse(substitute(x)), ', y=', deparse(substitute(y)),
                   ')) + geom_point() + geom_smooth()')
    p <- eval(parse(text = call))
    print(p)
    print(call)
}
```

#### Example

```
data("iris")
basic.plot.function('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width', iris)

> basic.plot.function('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width', iris)
`geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess'
[1] "ggplot(iris, aes_string(x=\"Sepal.Length\", y=\"Sepal.Width\")) + geom_point() + geom_smooth()"
```

[image]

#### Explanation

`desparse(substitute(x))` converts an argument `x` into a string. You can use that to make a string of the function call to print when printing your `ggplot` object. You can use `eval(parse())` to evaluate that string to make your `ggplot` object.